# Is it possible to get connect to Bluetooth Camera?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, bluetooth

I need to build an application which display the list of available Bluetooth Cameras and need to paired with them.I have search through the web,but unable to find any useful link.
any Tutorials/Sample code would greatly appreciated. !!

Thanks !!

Comment: i phase same problem in android please help....

Comment: Pairing for Bluetooth (not Bluetooth Low-Energy) with isn't done in app. It's done through Setting.app/Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy or Bluetooth 4.0) than the answer is YES. You can easily discover BLE devices in your app.

They identify using a specific UUID which you have to know to discover them. You will act as a so called BLE Central, the camera would be a Peripheral.

I don't know any Bluetooth cameras, but if they support BLE, you can refer to [Core Bluetooth framework reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html) or the [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH1-SW1).

If they don't support BLE, but the old Bluetooth, you would have to be member of the [MFi Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/). To be a member you would probably be a hardware manufacturer and have already products in stores. I also heard of individuals that got accepted, but you might probably not.

Long story short: BLE - YES, `!`BLE - NO.